# Step-definitions are not being found if I use newer Cucumber annotation interfaces like 'io.cucumber.java.en.Given'

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to use new Cucumber libraries (v4.8.0) in my project code and facing issue with feature & step-definition linking.

I had previous project in which I was using older version of Cucumber (v1.2.5).
Assuming that some setup was incorrect in my current project, I tried to match the Cucumber dependency in the previous project. But I encountered the same issue there as well

I also tried to verify the white spaces in my feature file, but had no success and the definitions were not identified

```
My Feature File:
    Feature: Feature Test
    Scenario: Scenario One
    Given Scenario One - Step One
```

My Definition File (using old annotation classes - definition gets identified):

```
 package definitions;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    public class Feature1 {
        @Given("Scenario One - Step One")
        public void stepOne() {
        }
    }
```

My Definition File (using new annotation classes - definition does not get identified):

```
package definitions;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
public class Feature1 {
    @Given("Scenario One - Step One")
    public void stepOne() {
    }
}
```

Expected results:
I am expecting that the new annotation classes should be able to identify & link the feature step & definition

Actual results:
Definitions gets identified if 'cucumber.api.java.en.Given' is used, but not identified if 'io.cucumber.java.en.Given' is used

Comment: Do you mean that your IDE can't find your step definitions or is Cucumber unable to find your step definitions when you run the tests.

Comment: Do you have the IDE's plugin installed? For instance, for Eclipse, install https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your reply.
Yes, I do have the Cucumber plugin installed in my IDE (Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)).

I did, however, find an alternate solution. If I use Cucumber version 4.4.0, my IDE is able to locate the step definitions. But, still no luck with the newer Cucumber version 4.8.0 :(

Comment: Could be that the plugin is not yet up to date with latest Cucumber version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating the following packages
cucumber version from 4.2.0 to 6.8.0

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I came from using the following in my step definiton java files

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
```

Then I updated the following packages

- cucumber version from 4.2.0 to 6.8.0
- gherkin version from 5.1.0 to 15.0.2

My Intellij didn't recognise my already implemented step definition anymore. ;-(

After I have replaces my imports with the next line it work all fine again

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
```

So I believe you need to update the version numbers from you cucumber version to use the new annotation classes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which got resolved using the below. Although it says deprecated, still StepDefinitions are linked to the Feature file.

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in my case also by replacing cucumber.api.java.en to io.cucumber.java.en.Given

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance provided in the previously posted answers?